# Отследить нажатие клавиши escape

Tags: linux, c

Есть такой код:

```
do
{
    printf("Сообщение: ");
    char message[BUFFER_SIZE];
    fgets(message, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
    printf("Длина: %d\n", strlen(message));
} while (1);
```

который считывает с клавиатуры строку и при нажатии на "Enter" совершает с ней какое-то действие. Как отследить нажатие клавиши "Escape" во время ожидания ввода строки и выйти из цикла? Либо какие-то другие решения моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Функция *fgets* возвращает управление только после того, как введёт символ перевода строки. Поэтому, с её помощью анализировать отдельный символ невозможно.

Если это вам действительно нужно (а я в этом не уверен), то можно воспользоваться функциями посимвольного ввода. Нечто вроде:

```
char ch;

while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' ) { // Выход по Enter

    switch(ch) {
       case '\033': // Код Esc
    . . .
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Бесполезно - ввод буферизован, пока не будет последнего Enter, толку не будет.

Comment: **Бесполезно - ввод буферизован** - Да, Вы правы - проверил. Ну значит - надо использовать ncurses! там точно возможен посимвольный ввод.

Answer (score 0):

Отслеживать нажатие конкретной клавиши с помощью стандартного буферизованного ввода не получится - обработка будет только по нажатии Enter. Сообветственно, нужно отслеживать небуферизованный ввод с помощью чего-то типа `getch()`, и тогда собирать строки самостоятельно, разбираясь, что именно было нажато, и обрабатывая простейшее редактирование строки типа всяких Backspace'ов - что обычно делают за вас...

Куда более простой вариант - некая стоп-строка - если введена она (ну, там, "quit", "exit" или на крайний случай "ПЦ" :)) - тогда завершать цикл.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы работает с командной строкой в linux можно воспользоватся библиотекой [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) очень простой и удобный интерфейс.